# Access Spinner in another activity

Tags: java, android

what is a good way to approach accessing spinner in another activity?
I have two dependent spinners , one is a bus route and another is bus stops within those routes. I want to access the list(spinner) of bus stops associated with the selected route in another activity.

Comment: If you use ViewModel, try this approach: share one ViewModel between the two Activities.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to save the value of the spinner. Than in your other activity, load the saved value.